# CCCrypt doesn't work on Xcode 4 and Xcode 5 (got different result)

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, xcode5

I try to use CCCrypt method, but I get different results from Xcode 3.2.6, Xcode 4 and Xcode 5; both have Mac OS X 10.6.
I have used following code to decrypt the data

```
- (NSData*)decryptData:(NSData*)data key:(NSData*)key iv:(NSData*)iv
{
    NSData* result = nil;

    // setup key
    unsigned char cKey[kCCKeySizeAES256];
    bzero(cKey, sizeof(cKey));
    cKey[0] = 0;
    [key getBytes:cKey length:kCCKeySizeAES256];

    // setup iv
    char cIv[kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    bzero(cIv, kCCBlockSizeAES128);
    if (iv) {
        [iv getBytes:cIv length:kCCBlockSizeAES128];
    }

    // setup output buffer
    size_t bufferSize = [data length] + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    // do decrypt
    size_t decryptedSize = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                                          kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                                          kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          cKey,
                                          kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          cIv,
                                          [data bytes],
                                          [data length],
                                          buffer,
                                          bufferSize,
                                          &decryptedSize);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        result = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:decryptedSize];
    } else {
        free(buffer);
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] failed to decrypt| CCCryptoStatus: %d", cryptStatus);
    }

    return result;
}
```

In Xcode 3.2.6 I get the actual result, whereas in Xcode 5 the result is "".

Comment: Sure you're running Xcode 5 on OS 10.6 .. ??

Comment: Best bet: Either the iv or key or both are not correct, possibly to short so some random data is getting into them. NSLog them and compare. Also the difference is not the Xcode version but the SDK used. In short CCCrypt works, re-think your code.

Comment: Xcode5 on Mountain Lion and XCode4.3.3 on Lion both have base sdk macosx10.6. And I am executing same code on this different platform.

Comment: @zaph I am Using CBC mode so that I have pass iv as a nil and I am also using correct key.

Comment: CBC mode requires a iv, ECB move does not.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet: Either the iv or key or both are not correct, possibly to short so some random data is getting into them. **NSLog them and compare**.

The difference is not the Xcode version but the SDK used. In short CCCrypt works, review your code.

CBC mode requires a iv, ECB mode does not.

Comment: You saved my ass after hours of futile googling.